# How to let the user control the number of communities generated in fast greedy community algorithm using dendplot

Tags: igraph

I am using fast greedy community algorithm to create communities. However i want an option where the user can limit the number of communities . I there an method for this. I heard this can be done through dendPlot. Need help on details

Comment: You can have any number of communities you want, see the `cutat()` at http://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html